# How to create dynamic (bootstrap) Accordion with XSLT

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xslt, accordion, umbraco

I am using bootstrap accordion to create a list of FAQs using XSLT. Its using the default 'collapse' javascript to toggle a heading to show description. See code below:

```
<div class="span9 faqswhole">   
  <xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/faqs"> 

    <div class="accordion" id="accordion">

      <!--accordion group-->        
      <div class="accordion-group"> 

        <!--faq title-->  
        <div class="accordion-heading">
          <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#faq1">
            <h3><xsl:value-of select="./faqTitle" /></h3>
          </a>
        </div>

        <!--faq description-->  
        <div id="faq1" class="accordion-body collapse in">
          <div class="accordion-inner">
            <p><xsl:value-of select="./faqText" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>                        
    </div>  
  </xsl:for-each>
</div>
```

I do understand that currently each div element is sharing an 'id' which connects it together. What I hope to do is that XSLT creates a dynamic accordion for each faq description (from doc types in Umbraco.

Currently all my buttons are only allowing toggle for the first FAQ detail, since the code (xsl:for-each select) is being applied

I would appreciate any ideas on how I can get around this please. Cheers!

Comment: `id`s need to be unique in the entire XHTML document, you can use a single class and listen for click events (e.g. in jQuery `$(".acc-entry").click(function(){$(this)...})` (`this` refers to the single clicked element).

Comment: Hi Marcus, 

Appreciate the speedy response. I will give this a go shortly. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can understand, you want the heading to be connected to the inner parts of the accordion by using the same id for both.

When using a for-each this can easily be done by calling the `position()` method within the for-each.

```
<div class="span9 faqswhole">   
  <xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/faqs"> 

    <div class="accordion" id="accordion">

      <!--accordion group-->        
      <div class="accordion-group"> 

        <!--faq title-->  
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                <xsl:text>#faq</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <h3><xsl:value-of select="./faqTitle" /></h3>
          </a>
        </div>

        <!--faq description-->  
        <div class="accordion-body collapse in">
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:text>faq</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                <p><xsl:value-of select="./faqText" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>                        
    </div>  
  </xsl:for-each>
</div>
```

I have not tested the code, so please let me know if it works!